# how to give up on editing a chat post

Tags: support, edits, chat

Help! While in [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com), I pressed my keyboard's up-arrow button (<kbd>↑</kbd>) to edit a previous post, and now I'm stuck editing it. How do I cancel that and post a new post instead?

Comment: This is already in the chat FAQ, why does it have to be in the community FAQ as well?

Comment: @balpha, "unlikely to ever help any future visitors"?? And I didn't realize there *is* a chat faq. Where is it?

Comment: http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/faq. Behind the FAQ link that's a few pixels to the right of your screenshot's edge, and in the header of most other chat chat pages.

Comment: @balpha, oh, thanks. This question's not on that FAQ list. In any event: "unlikely to ever help any future visitors"??

Comment: We don't have a "it's not the purpose of the community FAQ to duplicate the actual FAQ" close reason.

Comment: @balpha, oh, you're right: this shouldn't be on the community FAQ list if there's a chat FAQ list. So detag it [meta-tag:faq-proposed], sure; but why close it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two ways to cancel your edit and free up the input box:

- Press the escape button (<kbd>Esc</kbd>).
- Use the "Cancel editing" button to the right of the input box:

[image]

Any changes you made to the previous post will be lost.